# What is a good book for learning quantum mechanics with mathematical derivations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, mathematics, calculus

I know calculus (ODEs, PDEs, integration over 3 dimensions, limits, W, Zeta functions, series etc) and am working on linear algebra. What it the best book to learn quantum mechanics from with mathematical derviations?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/

Comment: Resource recommendation questions are allowed on this site but only under a [relatively restrictive policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697). In particular, minor variations in prerequisites do not make questions distinct under this policy, so this question is a duplicate of the threads linked in the banner above. If none of the resources linked there meet your needs, you should update this question to explain in detail what you're looking for as well as the resources you've seen and why they don't meet your needs.